# Kendo Ui ReferenceError in dynamic created form

Tags: kendo-ui

I am creating dynamic forms using remote server information.. My code is

```
$.ajax({
    url: xxx.php',
    data: {
        EXTAPP_ID: extappId,
        OBJECT_NAME: sessionStorage.getItem('ssObjectName')
    },
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (model) {
            console.log(model);
              obsRecordFields = kendo.observable(model);
            // bind the model to the container
            kendo.bind($("#recordDetailView"), obsRecordFields);
            kendo.init($("#Field1"));

    }
});
```

the template which is generating the form fields is

```
<script id="fieldsTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <li>
        <label data-bind="attr: { for: name}, text: label"></label>
         # if (get("fieldtype") == "input") {#
        <input data-bind="value: value, attr: { type: type, name: name}" # if (get("required")) {# required #} # />
            #}else{#
                    <select id="name" data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="source: options, value: value, attr: { type: type, name: name}" data-text-field="option_value" data-value-field="option_id"  />
            #}#

    </li>
</script>
```

my problem is

when I open the page the first time it returns an error in console log saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: option_id is not defined " when I refresh the same page and all the related function again, it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I made the ajax called inside the function that was triggered by data-init. The order of the events are

bind view model
beforeShow
init
show

So it started working when I triggered the function on data-show.

Thank you Spike for your very useful post (http://codingwithspike.wordpress.com/2012/12/31/kendo-mobile-gotchas-tips-tricks/) which helped to solve the problem.